# Unable to run tests in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a maven pom which I have imported into IntelliJ. The project builds fine and all. IntelliJ also does not show any compilation errors or squiggly lines anywhere, however strangely when I try to run unit tests it complains that some symbols cannot be found and so on. If I go to the file with the error I see no issues with the symbol.

I tried to Invalidate Cache and restart and that does not help. Any other pointers?

Comment: Does your maven project build correctly from a command line?

Comment: Are you running unit tests via intellij or via maven goals?

Comment: @SteveC my maven project builds fine from the command line and tests run fine too

Comment: @vikingsteve I want to run them through Intellij so that I can debug stuff. They do run fine on the command line.

Comment: Try to first reimport your maven project from the top level, so the intellij modules have the correct dependencies. Also do a full maven build in intellij, in case you have any code generation steps. After that, try to run the tests again.

Comment: Sometimes I get bugs like this and restarting intellij fixes it for me.  Have you tried restarting intellij yet?

Comment: Restarting did not fix it for me

Comment: Here is what worked for me finally! I used the Maven Projects mechanism to run the tests. After that I was able to get IntelliJ to run the same tests without using the Maven Projects way and even debug them.